# How should I configure nginx to serve both a web page and gitweb?

Tags: nginx, gitweb

I have installed nginx in my server and it is serving a *Hello World* website using SSL. I have also installed gitweb and I have configured it as shown in the [setting up Nginx for serving Git repositories over HTTP using Gitweb](https://gist.github.com/mcxiaoke/055af99e86f8e8d3176e) tutorial and it is working fine on port `4321`. I can access my *Hello World* website with `www.my-website.com` and gitweb with `www.my-website.com:4321` having two nginx sites-enabled:

`my-website`

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Server
    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;

    # Landing Page
    root /var/www/my-website.com/html;

    # Basic Authentication
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And `gitweb`

```
server {
    # Git repos are browsable at http://my-website.com:4321/
    listen 4321;

    # Basic Authentication
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location /index.cgi {
        root /usr/share/gitweb/;
        include fastcgi_params;
        gzip off;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
        fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/gitweb/;
        index index.cgi;
    }
}
```

I want to configure nginx to access the *Hello World* website as I normally do, with `www.my-website.com`, and gitweb with `www.my-website.com/git` but I haven't been able to do that.

This question, [How to serve GIT through HTTP via NGINX with user/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414227/how-to-serve-git-through-http-via-nginx-with-user-password/17553364), is almost perfect. The problem is that in there it is explained **how to substitute** the landing page by gitweb. If I configure nginx with the information from the answer to that question, then I can access gitweb just fine, as well as all individual projects, but I lose the *Hello World* page that I also need.

I then learned about **Reverse Proxying** and try to combine what I have with the *setting up Nginx for serving Git repositories over HTTP using Gitweb* tutorial to have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Server
    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;

    # Landing Page
    root /var/www/my-website.com/html;

    # Basic Authentication
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Attempt to access gitweb without the port number
    location /git {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4321/;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

That helped a little. Now the main gitweb page is shown when I enter `www.my-website.com/git`

[image]

**BUT** when I click on any of my projects, instead of opening them, I get this:

[image]

I have looked into other options like the [NGINX Configuration for Gitweb and git-http-backend](https://weinimo.github.io/configuration-of-nginx-for-gitweb-and-git-http-backend.html) tutorial but that also substitutes the Hello World web page and also is meant to configure to have HTTPS access to the repos **which is something I definitely don't want**. I clone them through ssh with PKI. Gitweb access is only for visualization, not cloning.

I also tried with [Configure nginx to serve two websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023671/configure-nginx-to-serve-two-websites) which seem promising since the question is similar to mine, but I get a `404 Not Found` when substituting `location /git {` with:

```
location /git {
    root /usr/share/gitweb/;
    index index.cgi;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I think my "combined approach", the one mentioned before is the right way to go, or is it? Should I add, remove, or modify something to not get the `about:blank#blocked`? or am I completely lost?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Server
    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;

    location / {
        # Landing Page
        root /var/www/my-website.com/html;

        # Basic Authentication
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /git/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321/;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm still getting the `about:blank#blocked`